# String was not recognize as a Valid datetime in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datagridview

I'm trying to highlight all the rows in the datagridview which date is more than five days from the date today. 
Here is my code.

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_Transfer_ledger.Rows
        Dim now As DateTime = Date.Now
        Dim delayDate = Date.Parse(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Dim fiveDaysbefore = delayDate.AddDays(-5)
        If now > fiveDaysbefore AndAlso now < delayDate Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        ElseIf now > delayDate Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
```

I'm getting the error `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.
Why I'm getting this error? Can anyone help me please? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The string cannot be parsed to a date. If you have a known fixed date format you can use `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: How I can declare the fixed date format?

Comment: Show what kind of `DateTime` format used in the your cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got the answer.

```
Dim currentdate As Date = Date.Now.ToString("d")
```

You have to format the date based on the datatype in your `datagridview`.
I didn't use `parse` or `ParseExact` for getting the delaydate. Just make sure that the cell format in `datagridview` is the same format of the current date :)
Thanks for the reference guys :)

Answer (score 0):

is your date in cell showing the correct format?
as they said, you need to check your cell's data and make sure it is in the correct format before they can actually run your code

if you know the format you may try
EG. **(DD/MM/YY) (MM/DD/YY)** [or something like this]

```
Dim delayDate = Date.ParseExact
```